# C# Inheritance with Different Assembly

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, .net-assembly

I have class A in assembly A with base functionality and I don't want to alter the functionality. I have another class B in assembly B where B overrides functionality of A.
Now I want to access Properties/methods of A in Class C which is in Assembly C, where I added reference of B in C.

How can i ?

Comment: Firstly, please show the code for A, B and C. Also **please use better names than A, B and C**. Perhaps, `Fruit`, `Citrus` and `Orange`. Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to add reference of `A.dll` in `C` assembly to get access of `A` class methods, if you were not using any of `A` class methods or properties directly from `C` then you didn't require that

Answer (score 0):

Assembly C needs references to both assemblies A and B. Then try this is your code:

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    public virtual void SayHelloFromA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello From A");
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public void SayHelloFromB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello From B");
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        var b = new ClassB();
        b.SayHelloFromA();
        b.SayHelloFromB();
    }
}
```